# Richfaces calendar "ü" (&#252) character problem

Tags: java, jsf, character-encoding, calendar, richfaces

I'm using Richfaces 3.3.3 and rich:calendar renders "&# 252;" instead of "ü" for month names. My explorer's encoding is UTF-8 and i tried the issue for all major explorers. They all rendered "&# 252;". My locale setting is "TR" which is for Turkish. If i summerize, "September" is rendered "Eyl"&# 252;"l" for Turkish.

Please don't mind the space at "&# 252;". I added it for this post, if i don't add a space this form renders "ü" :)

Do you have an idea for this problem?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: the locale is set where? On the calendar?

Comment: Thanks for the reply,

faces-config.xml is like below and also explorer's setting is TR. I have no other settings.

<application>
  <view-handler>com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler</view-handler>
  <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
  <locale-config>
   <default-locale>tr</default-locale>
   <supported-locale>tr</supported-locale>
   <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
  </locale-config>
 </application>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not related to the locale, but to HTML escaping. It is been HTML-escaped while it should not be. If you investigate the HTML source in webbrowser (rightclick, *View Source*), then there's a big chance that you see that it appears as `&amp;#252;` in there which get effectively displayed as `&#252;` in HTML.

It's unclear where those month name values originate and how they are rendered. If they originate in RichFaces itself and are rendered by RichFaces itself, then you can't do any much. It's likely a bug in RichFaces. You've got to report it yourself to the JBoss guys at [their homepage](http://www.jboss.org/richfaces/issuetracker).

But if you have control over those values and they are stored as Java properties files and/or read into a string by Java code, then you should replace `&#252;` by `\u00fd` which is the Java encoding of [Unicode Character 'LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00fc/index.htm). Or if you have control over outputting/rendering the values, then you should add `escape="false"` attribute to the output component.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed reply. Richfaces renders the month names, so i have no chance to manipulate them. When i checked the HTML, I realized that it is calling Richfaces.Calendar.addLocale() javascript function. And function's parameters are month names. It is writing &#252; also there. Some characters coded with Java encoding like \u0131 but some of them are coded like &#252;. You are right, it is better to report the issue to the JBoss. I will share the result of issue on this post. Thanks a lot again, happy new year!